# Is there anything conceptually wrong with regressing Y on X and 1/X?

Tags: multiple-regression

Say I have the following regression (assume the Gauss Markov assumptions hold):

$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \beta_2 \frac{Z_i}{X_i} + u_i$$

Is there anything conceptually wrong with this, eg endogeneity?

Comment: There is conceptually nothing wrong with this idea. In fact, you basically added an interaction term to the regression model.